# Symfony cache clear and memory limit

Tags: php, symfony, caching, putty

I am trying to clear the cache of my web app, on Putty:

`php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

However I get a `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted...`

I changed my .user.ini to 128M and the info.php displays the proper value of 128M. However when I run the command in putty, I still get a message

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted...`

Why is the display correct on info.php and incorrect in the error message?

Comment: I know it's quick&dirty©, ugly and what-not but you could still clear the cache by simply removing everything from `cache` directory...

Comment: I did this but it takes a very long time via my secure webdisk connection. Did work a lot faster through cPanel File Manager. However, I would still like not to have to do this each time.

Comment: Yes, without terminal access it's really not an option :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that the PHP that runs via the web and the PHP that runs from the command line use different ini files. Try `php -i` from the command line and see which ini file it uses. Alternatively try the `php -c your.ini.file` to specify an alternate ini file.

See the full list of options here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Edit: As requested, the specific command line to use:

```
php -c /some/dir/your.php.ini app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: Indeed, when I type in `php -i` I see a limit of 64M. I tried `php -c / php.ini` and I put the php.ini in the root folder. The command then displays the php ini file but nothing changes after i do php -i.

Comment: Btw, it doesn't change the results from `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'`

Comment: Don't put a space between the slash and the filename. The fact that it displays the `php.ini` file means the `php.ini` file was processed as input. Adding `-c` will change the configuration file used for *that* run of php, not future runs so try `php -c your.php.ini app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Ok, I'll try at a downtime of my website! I tried this: `php -c /php.ini -i` and it does work wonders for info is then 128M. Thanks! Can you add that in your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 5+

`php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`